# Logging error in ASP.Net Core and be able to read it

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, logging, azure-web-app-service

I have created a ASP.Net Core 5  WebApi.  It comes with the out of the box logging capabilities.
I have two questions.

1. After I reference it in the class should I add try and catch block to capture and log the error or error will log itself?
2. where can I see the logs.  Like in ASP.NET Classics we would define the file in webconfig file and would be able to read the error or information in defined file? I would be deploying this app in Azure app service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After I reference it in the class should I add try and catch block to capture and log the error or error will log itself?

Unhandled exceptions will be logged by the framework.

> where can I see the logs. Like in ASP.NET Classics we would define the file in webconfig file and would be able to read the error or information in defined file? I would be deploying this app in Azure app service.

There probably is a line somewhere in your Program.cs file like this `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0) this will perform the following action

> Configure the ILoggerFactory to log to the console, debug, and event source output.

There is a [lot of documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) arround logging. You could setup logging to write to a 3rd party system like nlog of log4net, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#third-party-logging-providers-1) , or write to a built-in provider, see [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#built-in-logging-providers-1).

For web apps ,[Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#azure-application-insights-1) is a good choice, or to the [Azure App Service Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#azure-app-service-1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use System.IO to write to a text file. For example, something like this -

```
        // create file 

        string strPath = @"C:\errors.txt";

        if (!File.Exists(strPath))
        {
            File.Create(strPath).Dispose();
        }
        try
        {
            // code
        }
        catch (ex)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(strPath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Nowadays we have abstractions like the `ILogger` interface that help us to avoid manually having to write our own logging logic and be able to use a well implemented logging library withouth having to worry about specific implementation details.